# get slug of all ativate plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want a list of all active slug plugins in Wordpress . Is there any function in Wordpress  to get it. I have searched google for the same but only got the list of all plugin details except slug name.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin hasn't slug.
But you can get a list of all active plugins like this :

```
$all_plugins = get_plugins();
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

// echoes the main file plugin if it's active
foreach($all_plugins as $key => $plugin)
    if( is_plugin_active($key) )
        echo "<div>" . $key . "</div>";
```

I hope that help you !